# pafy and vlc audio only in python

Tags: python, vlc, pafy

I am trying to write a small python program to play audio only from youtube links. The idea is that I want to make a small player for my son that doesn't need a tv, just some speakers. I can create playlists for him and then load them up in this player and there will be music but no image. But since I am really new to python I am having some trouble:

After some research I settled on vlc and pafy. 
First I tried with vlc only, but the `python-vlc` module seems to play the video too without other arguments like the `--no-video` command line argument that can be passed to vlc to only listen to the audio stream.

Then I read about `pafy` that can extract the audio url and can be passed to vlc. I have tried it using this code but I get no audio. The code runs for a few seconds then it stops.

```
import pafy                                                                                                                                 
import vlc                                                                                                                                  
#                                                                                                                                           
#                                                                                                                                           
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0OqIkgZqlA"                                                                                         
video = pafy.new(url)                                                                                                                       
best = video.getbestaudio()                                                                                                                 
playurl = best.url                                                                                                                          
player = vlc.MediaPlayer(playurl)                                                                                                           
player.play()
```

What am I doing wrong? Also can this be achieved with python2.7 only? I mean no python 3 stuff.

Comment: add `while True: pass` after of `player.play()`

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand... Can you please elaborate a bit? I am really really new to python...

Comment: What part of my comment is not clear ?, just add `while True: pass` at the end of your code

Comment: Ok sorry, I just don't understand why, but I will try it! Thank you

Comment: great stuff! it works! thanks, I'll investigate the rest in the documentation